# MongoDB query with geoWithin works wrong

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geometry, geospatial

I have a question connected with `mongoDB`. Let's represent we have a collection `points`, in which we have an one point:

```
db.points.insert(
  {
    name: 'point1',
    location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-11, -1]
    }
  }
);
```

I wrote the following query with `geoWithin`:

```
let foundPoints = db.points.find(
    {
        location: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: 'Polygon',
                    coordinates: [[[-15, -5], [-5, 5], [-5, -5], [-15, -5]]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

const answer = foundPoints.map(doc => doc.name);
```

Let's see that the point `[-11, -1]` is on the side of the given triangle, but the query didn't find the point. I want to know which I did wrong. Can you help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point (-11,-1) is only on the line from (-15,-5)-(-5,5) if those are coordinates in a plane.

If those are longitude and latitude on a sphere, the point (-11,-1) is outside of that triangle.

Plot the point and triangle at https://geojson.io, that point is actually about 100 meters northwest of the triangle.